# Проблема с сохранением canvas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, canvas

Есть `div`, из содержимого этого `div` формируется `canvas`,потом я пытаюсь сохранить это в `png`

```
$("#s_img1").click(function (){

 html2canvas($("#tableWrap"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {

                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);


                $("canvas").attr("id", "canv");
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);

            }
        });
    var data = document.getElementById("canv").toDataURL();

    $.post("process.php", {
imageData : data
}, function(data) {
window.location = data;
  });

   var myCanvas = $(document).find('#canv');
  var myImg = myCanvas.get(0).toDataURL();



alert(myImg);

});
```

Проблема в том,что консоль дает ошибку на `toDataURL();`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of undefined
```

Подскажите в чем проблема? 
Вот `process.php`

```
$data = substr($_POST['imageData'], strpos($_POST['imageData'], ",") + 1);
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);
$fp = fopen("canvas.png", 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
fclose();
echo "/canvas.png";
```

Тут html

```
<div id="tableWrap"></div>
<br />

<br /><br />

<br /> <input type="button" id="s_img1" value="Сохранить" />
<div id="img-out"></div>
            <hr>
           <input type="button" id="all_save" value="All" />
<img id="canvasImg" alt="Right click to save me!">
```

Comment: попробуйте так: html2canvas($("#tableWrap").get(0), {

Comment: Все равно эта ошибка

Comment: @zkolya, дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос куском HTML кода с которым вы работаете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема том, что при вызове  var myCanvas = $(document).find('#canv');
элемент canv еще  не создано. 
Так будет работать:

```
function CallPost(postdatа) {

        $.post("process.php", {imageData: postdatа})
               .done(function (data) {               
                 window.location = 'canvas.png';               
               });
 }    

 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#s_img1").click(function () {    
                html2canvas($("#tableWrap"), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        CallPost(canvas.toDataURL());
                     }
                });        
            });
  });
```

Comment: А Вы не подскажите,почему мне на ReferenceError: postdata is not defined ругается?

Comment: Исправил! Попробуй это.

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам,все заработало!